# Displaying a paginated list of forum topics using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, pagination

Can someone tell me if this code is safe? Can be sql-injected or something else hacked? Code get some rows from db and show in pages with pagination... if i can improve let me know and show me how, thanks.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=admin_admin', 'admin_admin', 'password');
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
     $num_rows = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a_topics')->fetchColumn(); 
     $pages = new Paginator($num_rows,25,array(25,50,100,250,'All'));
     $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT a_topics.pid, a_topics.title, a_topics.forum_id, b_forums.id, b_forums.name 
        FROM a_topics INNER JOIN b_forums ON a_topics.forum_id = b_forums.id
        ORDER BY a_topics.pid DESC LIMIT :start,:end');
     $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
     echo $pages->display_jump_menu().$pages->display_items_per_page();
     echo $pages->display_pages();
        foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "$row[0] - $row[1] - $row[2]";
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is **safe** from the SQL injection standpoint but it is likely **prone to XSS** because of the untreated output, and also to possibly leak the sensitive information due to the error message unconditionally spat out.

Regarding other improvements I would suggest a [more robust connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) and to avoid bindParam calls thanks to [disabled emulation mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit).

The rewritten code would be

```
include 'pdo.php';
$num_rows = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a_topics')->fetchColumn(); 
$pages = new Paginator($num_rows,25,array(25,50,100,250,'All'));
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT a_topics.pid, a_topics.title, a_topics.forum_id, b_forums.id, b_forums.name 
    FROM a_topics INNER JOIN b_forums ON a_topics.forum_id = b_forums.id
    ORDER BY a_topics.pid DESC LIMIT :start,:end');
$stmt->execute(['start' => $pages->limit_start, 'end' => $pages->limit_end]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo $pages->display_jump_menu().$pages->display_items_per_page();
echo $pages->display_pages();
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($row[0]),
         " - ", 
         htmlspecialchars($row[1]),
         " - ", 
         htmlspecialchars($row[2])";
}
```

Comment: I undestand thank you. One more question and i'm done, what if i use --> if ($_GET["id"] == "$row[0]" { echo "page1"; } <-- inside foreach, is safe?